# Change Code from DCT to Inverse Discrete Cosine Transformation?

Tags: java, image, compression, jpeg, dct

For an project I have to demonstrate JPEG compression and therefore the conversion with DCTII and IDCT. I have no idea how to implement this formula. But I found an website that provides the Java code and online IDE for testing.
https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/FnC3bRJEAr here you can see the code.

[image: formula for DCT]
[image: formula for IDCT]

(formulas from Wikipedia/JPEG)

So, what changes have to be made to the code?

I tried switching the for-loops and the variables in the formula but the values I got were definitely wrong, other tries lead to error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between the DCT and IDCT is where coefficient are taken into account.

You should replace line 46 in your code by

```
sum = sum + ck*cl*dct1;
```

where ck and cl are computed as in lines 24-34, but for k and l

And suppress ci*cj in line 49

BTW, this java code is exceptionally inefficient. Precompute Math.sqrt(2), Math.sqrt(n) and put your cosine in a table and it will be at least 3 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your summations are doing a matrix multiplication. Your a multiplying an 8x8 data matrix by an 8x8 DCT matrix.

The DCT matrix is orthonormal so its inverse is its transpose.

You should therefore be able to invert by exchanging u and v.

Comment: You are amazing! This helped me SO much!